# Rails: Copyright headers for GPLv3 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, open-source, copyright-display

We are developing a project in `Rails` and planning to open source it under `GPLv3`.

I have the following questions regarding this:

1. To which files should we add the copyright header? Only the `.rb` files in `lib`, `controller`, `model`, `helpers`, `config` etc? How about the `.erb`, `.js`, and `.css` files?
2. Should we add the detailed GPLv3 header to the source files? Or a few liner with a pointer to some external file in the project or a URL to GPL site would be suffice?

I have looked into a couple of open source projects developed in `Rails`. Some of them have added the copyright header in `.rb` files. Few have added in some other file type too.

This could be a matter of preference, but I am looking for best practices in this regard.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: each file should contain this http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-howto.html, and a LICENSE file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical practice is to simply include a single `LICENSE` file at the top directory of the application, containing the full license text and any addendums.  It's also common to include the license text or a link to it on the home page of the project (see many GitHub open source projects for examples).  I'm not a lawyer, so I can't say how protections vary if you only include a single top-level license vs. a copyright notice in every file, but in practice you'll rarely see it all over the place.

Comment: Thanks Jim for your input. I'd love others to give some suggestions too. Thanks again.